# In intellij while creating new spring project nit able to see java version below 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-11

I want to create a spring project with java version 11. In project sdk I set jdk11 but on the next screen in the java version in drop down there is no version 11. It starts from version 17.

If i select jdk 11 and java 17 it gives pop "selected java version 17" not supported.
I have screenshots of the same.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtx7n.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4LMb.jpg)

I have put my jdk path in env variable but it is not working

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA's Spring Boot project creation functionality is based on the underlying open-source Spring Initializr project: github.com/spring-io/initializr. Requiring higher versions of Java is their call. The IDE just complies with it. 
As a workaround, you can create the project using higher versions of Java/Spring in IDEA, then change the versions in pom.xml manually and reload the dependencies.
For a more detailed explanation and instructions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77570193/alternative-website-for-spring-initializr-for-java-8-start-spring-io-now-only

Answer (score 2):

## Feature, not a bug

Spring Boot 3.0 **requires Java 17** or later.

See [*Spring Boot 3.0 Migration Guide*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide).

See https://start.spring.io/